Power BI keeps displaying 12:00:00 AM. How can I make it display the right time?
I'm currently getting the data from a Sharepoint List into my Power BI Desktop.
The time on the Sharepoint list is displayed correctly but when I view it in my Power BI table, it only shows 12:00:00 AM for all of the entries.
i.e: 4/12/2024 12:00:00 AM
But the time is suppose to be 4/12/2024 1:10 PM
How can I get it to display the right time in Power BI?

In power query,

convert datetime column to a text
split column to get date and time columns
concat columns together
format column as datetime.

